# How to access a property of a tableview cell from viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Please see screenshot. There is a `repliesTableView, replyTextField and replyButton`in `ViewController`. `repliesTableView cell` is called `ReplyCell`. In `ReplyCell` there is a `commentTableView` to list all comments for that reply and a `textfField, a commentButton` to add new comments.

I have problem when add new replies and new comments. I guess I need to  make `comments array` in `ReplyCell` empty when I click the `Reply button`. How can I make this happen? I have no idea how to access `comments array`from the root `ViewController`.

Exact problems: fter clicking commentButton, all comments in every cell doubled. After clicking replyButton, comments went to wrong cell.

[image]  [image]

```
Code: 



import UIKit
import Firebase

class TopicForumVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var topicNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var replyNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var repliesTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var replyTextField: UITextField!


var topicName:String?

var firstKey:String?

var secondKey:String?

var replies = [String]()

var replyButtonTapped = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    repliesTableView.delegate = self
    repliesTableView.dataSource = self

    replyTextField.delegate = self

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    topicNameLabel.text = self.topicName

    loadReplies()
}

func loadReplies() {

    self.replies = []

    DataService.ds.Categories_Base.child(self.firstKey!).child("Topics").observe(.value, with:{(snapshot) in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {

                if let topicDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                    if let topic = topicDict["text"] as? String {

                        if topic == self.topicName {

                            self.secondKey = snap.key

                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(snap.key, forKey: Key_SecondKey)

                            if let replyDict = topicDict["replies"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                                for eachDict in replyDict {

                                    if let textDict = eachDict.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                                        if let reply = textDict["text"] as? String {

                                            self.replies.append(reply)
                                            self.replyNumberLabel.text = String(self.replies.count)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            self.repliesTableView.reloadData()
        }

    })

}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return replies.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReplyCell") as? ReplyCell  {

         let reply = replies[indexPath.row]

           cell.configureReplyCell(reply: reply)

            return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}


@IBAction func replyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    replyButtonTapped = true

    if let reply = replyTextField.text, reply != "" {

        self.replies = []

        DataService.ds.Categories_Base.child(self.firstKey!).child("Topics").child(self.secondKey!).child("replies").childByAutoId().child("text").setValue(reply)

        self.repliesTableView.reloadData()

        let i = replies.count

        for n in 0..<i {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: n, section: 1)

            let cell = repliesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ReplyCell

            cell.comments = []

            cell.repliesToReplyTableView.reloadData()


        }

        self.replyTextField.text = ""

        self.replyButtonTapped = false
    }

  }
```

}

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase


class ReplyCell:    UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var replyTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var repliesToReplyTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var commentTextField: UITextField!

var reply:String?

var comments = [String]()

var replyKey:String?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.comments = []

    repliesToReplyTableView.delegate = self
    repliesToReplyTableView.dataSource = self

    commentTextField.delegate = self

        loadComments()

}

func configureReplyCell(reply:String) {

    self.reply = reply

    self.replyTextView.text = self.reply
}

func loadComments() {

    self.comments = []

    if let firstKey = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Key_FirstKey) as? String, let secondKey = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Key_SecondKey) as? String {

        DataService.ds.Categories_Base.child(firstKey).child("Topics").child(secondKey).child("replies").observe(.value, with:{(snapshot) in

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots {

                    if let replyDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                        if let reply = replyDict["text"] as? String {

                            if  reply == self.reply {

                                self.replyKey = snap.key

                                DataService.ds.Categories_Base.child(firstKey).child("Topics").child(secondKey).child("replies").child(snap.key).child("comments").observe(.value, with: { (commentSnapshot) in

                                    if let commentSnapshots = commentSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                                        for commentSnap in commentSnapshots {

                                            if let commentDict = commentSnap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                                                if let comment = commentDict["text"] as? String {

                                                    self.comments.append(comment)

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                      self.repliesToReplyTableView.reloadData()

                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        })

    }

}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let commentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CommentCell")

    commentCell?.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]

     return commentCell!
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}


@IBAction func commentBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if let comment = commentTextField.text, comment != "" {

        self.comments = []

        if let firstKey = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Key_FirstKey) as? String, let secondKey = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Key_SecondKey) as? String {

         DataService.ds.Categories_Base.child(firstKey).child("Topics").child(secondKey).child("replies").child(self.replyKey!).child("comments").childByAutoId().child("text").setValue(comment)

            if let myViewController = parentViewController as? TopicForumVC {

             //   myViewController.repliesTableView.reloadData()

                myViewController.replies = []
            }


            self.repliesToReplyTableView.reloadData()

            self.commentTextField.text = ""
            self.replyKey = ""
    }


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know the exact circumstances of what you're building but there are two ideas that may offer some guidance.

1) If your table is displaying content from a data source then you will likely have some kind of reference. E.g. when loading the cells (in this case `CustomCell`) you'll do something like `get the index of the cell` and `get the same index from the data`, and `put that data in the cells content`. If that's the case, all you have to do on the button click is use `tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath` with your sender object, and then remove the array from the data source, e.g. `tableDataSource[index] = nil` and reload the tableView.

2) If you have a stored property on the CustomCell that you've add specifically for storing this array, then you'd cast the sender object to `CustomCell` and remove the property, as in Kim's answer.

Hope this helps, but without more information it's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I added a screenshot and revised my question to make it clearer. Can you take a minute to review and advise your comments? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @developermike could you make the image a bit bigger?

Comment: @developermike They look very blurry in my browser, hard to make out what's going on.

Comment: This time should be fine. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @developermike thanks for the updated image. How are you populating the  comments tableview in the cell?

Comment: Is it a good idea I upload the code to github and you help me? Thanks!

Comment: @developermike if you can, paste all the relevant code in your original post.  I've not used firebase and still not entirely sure how the data is getting to the tableview. But I'll have a think once you paste some code.

Comment: I just added code for two tableview. So far please don't worry about the Firebase part, I think the problem may be I added another tableview into an first tableviewcell. When there was only the first Replytableview, it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: I added exact problems in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(...) as? CustomCell
if cell != nil {
     let arr = cell.array
}
```

BTW: I would re-think storing your array in the cell..

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for your time. I added a screenshot and revised my question. I wanted to make comments array in each ReplyCell empty, not specifically which indexPath. So your current answer didn't help. Can you review and advise?